# Instalar mongoDB en Debian 11 error ILL

Tags: mongodb

estoy intentando instalar mongoDB en debian 11 bullseye pero me da un error ILL
proceso de instalacion:

- sudo apt install gnupg
- wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
- echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/5.0 main" | sudo tee
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
- apt update
- apt install mongodb-org
- systemctl start mongod
- systemctl enabled mongod
  pero al momento de ejecutar : sudo systemctl status mongod tengo este error:
  root@debian11:~# sudo systemctl status mongod
  ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2023-09-07 11:19:53 -05; 1min 23s ago
  Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Main PID: 3841 (code=killed, signal=ILL)
  CPU: 13ms

set 07 11:19:53 debian11 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
set 07 11:19:53 debian11 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=4/ILL
set 07 11:19:53 debian11 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
root@debian11:~#